# Logistic Regression mean square error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**NOTE:** I appreciate the massive quantity of comments suggesting that this is inappropriate to quantify model performance.  However, this is irrelevant to my error, and this error occurs for a variety of other metrics.  Also, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels) for the appropriate way to respond when you think the OP is "asking the wrong question"

I have an sklearn logistic model for which I am attempting to get the RMSE.  However, when I `.predict_proba`, I get a vector of probabilities.  However, my `y_test` is in its categorical form, which `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` just sort of dealt with automagically.

How to I reconcile these two things to get the RMSE?

```
>>> sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_proba, sample_weight=weights_test)
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=13)
```

Comment: Predict proba is predicting the probability that a sample belongs to a class. The arg max of the probabilities is the predicted class (categorical form). RMSE is not a metric for classification.

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase your question and point it to a metric that actually would be used to quantify classification performance.

Comment: @Sören.  RMSE is the metric used to train the model!  I also need to transform the probabilities into logits, but note that my question DOES NOT say anything about classification performance.

Comment: Also, @Everyone, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/rmse-root-mean-squared-error-for-logistic-models/172985#172985) that using accuracy is not necessarily a good way to measure performance.

Comment: But that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Can you post a code sample? How are you getting LogisticRegression to use RMSE?? In case of binary classification it uses cross-entropy loss. Not RMSE.

Comment: @Sören I was under the impression that the "l2" penalty was the loss applied to the logits, implying [IRLS optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), but upon further reading of the docs I see that this is not the case.  I will update my note, but in any case, this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Can you print the lengths of you prediction and the target? They should be the same.

Comment: Please, print the types and the lengths of your input `y_test` and `pred_proba` and post examples to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Sören, the lengths are the same, but the shape is different.  `y_test` is a categorical variable, shape = `(num_samples,1)`.  It contains values like `"some_string_or_another"`.  `pred_proba` is a vector of probabilities, of shape `(num_samples, 13)`, because apparently there were 13 unique values in my `y_test` before I passed it.  My solution below seems to halfway solve this problem.

Comment: An interesting edge case which this does not solve is if one's data is very imbalanced, and `y_train` does not contain classes that `y_test` contains.  Unfortunately, `LogisticRegression.fit` does not allow one-hot `y` to work around this.

Comment: I think, they should have the same shape, and they should be one-dimensional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One can transform the `y_test` into a format compatible with the `predict_proba` output as follows:

```
model = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X,y) # or whatever model
label_encoder = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.classes_ = model.classes_
y_test_onehot = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(label_encoder.transform(y_test).reshape((-1,1)))
```

You can now apply any of the metrics in `sklearn.metric`.  This is essential for computing, say, the brier score.

Answer (score 0):

`predict_proba` is predicting the probability that a sample belongs to a class. The arg max of those probabilities is the predicted class (categorical form). RMSE is not a metric for classification. If you want to evaluate your model, consider a different metric like `accuracy_score`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
predictions = your_model.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy: %.3f" % accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

Comment: RMSE is the metric used to fit the curve, which is why I wanted it.

Comment: Also, my categories are not on $[0,n]$, so argmax of the `predict_proba`s cannot possibly be the predicted class.

Comment: The `predict` code from sklearn literally uses argmax: `indices = scores.argmax(axis=1)`. I think you are misunderstanding logistic regression

Comment: Actually, RMSE is used to fit the curve over the logits, not the probas.  So one needs to do some manipulating to the raw `probas` and `y_test`s, but this runs into the same problem I have posed, and is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: there must be some additional logic to translate to a label.  That line is relevant, however.  Can you provide a link?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L311

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can calculate RMSE:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
x = np.range(10)
y = x
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(x, y))
```

Comment: That is, in fact, not what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The brier score, basically the mean squared error, is a known and valid loss function for classification models that leverage probability scores; I would take a look at that as well.

To your particular issue, you want to compare the probabilities returned for your target class, i.e. for a binary class problem:

```
from sklearn.metrics import brier_score_loss

probs = your_model.predict_proba(X_test)
brier_score_loss(y_true, probs[:, 1])
```

I'm not sure brier is formally defined for multiclass problems. I would point to the idea of mean misclassification error, which averages the error across classes.

To leverage this within the sklearn API, encode your y_true categorically, i.e. each class gets its own column, and call

sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, probs, multioutput=’uniform_average’)

Comment: My problem is not binary.  How do I translate between my `y_true`, which is categorical, and a `predict_proba` index?